# GNU make re-evaluation of dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a program that depends on a library that is built by a separate makefile.
The main makefile does not properly detect that the library has been rebuilt and therefore does not recreate my program.

The main `Makefile` can be simplified (just using `touch` to represent the actual compilation) as this. It always calls the sub-make to make sure that libA is up to date without needing to know about its dependecies.

```
progA: srcA libA
    touch $@

libA: make_libA_if_needed

.PHONY: make_libA_if_needed
make_libA_if_needed:
    make -f Makefile.libA libA

clean:
    rm -f progA libA
```

The second makefile `Makefile.libA` can be simplified as this

```
libA: libsrcA
    touch $@
```

This works as expected when the libA does not exists or does not need to be rebuilt

```
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $ touch srcA libsrcA
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $ make
make -f Makefile.libA libA
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
touch libA
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
touch progA
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $ make
make -f Makefile.libA libA
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
make[1]: 'libA' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $
```

However, if I update libsrcA I need to run make twice in order for progA to be rebuilt properly.

```
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $ touch libsrcA
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $ make
make -f Makefile.libA libA
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
touch libA
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $ make
make -f Makefile.libA libA
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
make[1]: 'libA' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jronnber/tmp'
touch progA
jronnber@jronnber-mobl:~/tmp $
```

Is this a bug in make or can I change my `Makefile` somehow to detect that libA has been rebuilt by the sub-make in `make_libA_if_needed`?

Comment: Are you talking about re-linking when the library .a changes, or recompiling when its headers change?

Comment: Relinking when the library .a changes.

Comment: Hmm. I think I'd update the library from a `$(shell)` function, to do it before the makefile finishes parsing, and then just add a dependency from `progA` to the .a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not sufficient:

```
libA: make_libA_if_needed
```

GNU Make knows that there is no recipe here and so it didn't run a command to update that target, so it "knows" that the target hasn't been modified.  You can add a dummy recipe to the rule so that make realizes that this target might have been updated (even if the recipe is empty, make still considers that it might have been updated).

So change the above line to this:

```
libA: make_libA_if_needed ;
```

(note the added semicolon).  Or if you prefer you could use this:

```
libA: make_libA_if_needed
        @: do nothing
```

or whatever.

An alternate way to go is to use a FORCE rule instead of .PHONY.  .PHONY is a very big stick and tells make to always rebuild the target AND to assume it was out of date.  But the FORCE trick ensures the target is rebuilt without assuming it was out of date.  That would look like this:

```
libA: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.libA $@
FORCE:
```

(note you should *always* use `$(MAKE)` to invoke sub-makes, never `make`).  In this model you don't need the `make_libA_if_needed` target.

Note the actual name of the target `FORCE` is just a convention; you can call this anything you like.  You can also declare it to be `.PHONY` if you want to be extra safe.